# Finding a basis for a set of polynomials in P3 where f'(2) = f(1) as two polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

So far I've done the following.

$f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

$f'(x) = 3ax^2+2bx+c$

$f'(2)=f(1)$

$12a+4b+c=a+b+c+d$

So, $d=11a+3b$

Leaving you so far with

$ax^3+bx^2+cx+11a+3b$

Giving you

$(x^3+11)a+(x^2+3)b+cx$

But the basis must be given as two polynomials in the question. I don't know how to make this any simpler to leave me with 2 polynomials.

Comment: So, you're supposed to find the subspace of polynomials $f \in P_3$ such that $f'(2) = f(1)$, and find a basis of two vectors? It can't be done; the subspace is three-dimensional. Are there no other restrictions on this set? Or perhaps it's a typo, and $P_2$ was intended.

Comment: No other restrictions, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility of a typo. It has happened before in the assignments for the course I'm taking. As you said, the answer is rather simple with $P_2$.

Comment: Typo it is, then. If I were you, I would finish the question, finding a basis of $3$ vectors. Then, appeal to the dimension theorem: say that the subspace cannot have bases of two different sizes.